# Plain java project vs Spring boot project (Interactive brokers integration)

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, sockets, interactive-brokers

I am little confused about the Spring boot application runtime lifecycle. The thing is I have a plain java project that is just running fine connect into Interactive Brokers Socket server (TWS workstation). But I want to migrate into a new Spring boot application. Because I think this is more safe and easy to maintenance. Because every time, I upgrade Jar libraries in plain java project that is so much work to do to me. Otherwise, Spring boot application is so much easy to upgrade dependencies and eager to add new features.

So here is example code in plain java project. Of course I already added TWS.jar (Interactive brokers SDK):

```
        ...
        EWrapperImpl wrapper = new EWrapperImpl();

        final EClientSocket m_client = wrapper.getClient();
        final EReaderSignal m_signal = wrapper.getSignal();
        //! [connect]
        System.out.println("working....");
        m_client.eConnect("127.0.0.1", 7497, 2);
        System.out.println("client connected!");
        //! [connect]
        //! [ereader]
        final EReader reader = new EReader(m_client, m_signal);

        reader.start();
        //An additional thread is created in this program design to empty the messaging queue
        new Thread(() -> {
            while (m_client.isConnected()) {
                m_signal.waitForSignal();
                try {
                    reader.processMsgs();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.println("Exception: "+e.getMessage());
                }
            }
        }).start();
        ...
```

This code working absolutely fine. It can create active a client connection to TWS

But in the Spring boot project I created this Component class:

```
@Log4j2
@Component
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class Tester {

    private final IBCache cache;

    @PostConstruct
    void initialize() {
        Contract contract = new Contract();
        contract.secType("NEWS");
        contract.exchange("BRF");

        EJavaSignal signal = new EJavaSignal();
        IBReceiver receiver = new IBReceiver();
        log.info("Receiver initialized");

        EClientSocket socket = new EClientSocket(receiver, signal);

        log.info("TWS info: {}, {}, {}", this.cache.getHostname(), this.cache.getPort(), this.cache.getClientId());
        socket.eConnect(cache.getHostname(), cache.getPort(), cache.getClientId());
        log.info("Socket connecting...");
        EReader reader = new EReader(socket, signal);
        reader.start();
//        Reader worker = new Reader(reader);
//        Reader worker = new Reader(reader);
//        worker.run();
        socket.reqContractDetails(Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(Math.random() + 1)), contract);
    }
}
```

In this class, IBCache provide connection info:

1. Hostname -> 127.0.0.1
2. Port -> 7497
3. clientId -> 2

But when I run spring boot application, that application throw exception all the time. Message:

> ErrorCode: 502
>
> ErrorMessage: Couldn't connect to TWS. Confirm that
> "Enable ActiveX and Socket Clients" is enabled and connection port is
> the same as "Socket Port" on the TWS "Edit->Global
> Configuration...->API->Settings" menu. Live Trading ports: TWS: 7496;
> IB Gateway: 4001. Simulated Trading ports for new installations of
> version 954.1 or newer: TWS: 7497; IB Gateway: 4002

What should I do?

Comment: I already config my trader workstation. that is working fine